# Why doesn't the repeat() function repeat spaces in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to pad a varchar field in Snowflake with spaces. I'm using the repeat function. LPAD function was similarly disappointing.

```
select concat('|', repeat(' ',10), '|') concat_result
union
select concat('|', repeat('_',10), '|')
```

[image: 1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a product of the UI, not what is happening in the data.  Try this and you'll see what I mean:

```
SELECT LENGTH( concat('|', repeat(' ',10), '|') );
```

Result: 12

Answer (score 1):

For generating specific number of spaces built-in [`SPACE`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/space.html) function could be used:

> **SPACE(n)**
>
> Builds a string consisting of the specified number of blank spaces.

```
SELECT SPACE(10)
```